# SQL Replace with wildcards

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace

I am slowly finding out that the replace string does not work with Wildcards.  What I have is approx 10 SKUs, these 10 SKUs each have approx 20 sub SKUs.

Example: _Example - Parent SKU
         Example7bTL - Child SKU

-End result would be to turn all child SKUs into _Example so i can get a sum of units sold in a clean format.

what i currently have for reference.

```
use test


CREATE TABLE #test (
Test int,
BillQty char(300) )


select   Quantity, REPLACE (SKU,  '%EXAMP%', 'Example') As Sku
from test.dbo.tblSFCOrderTxn




drop table #Test
```

---

```
Raw Data Example---

Quantity        SKU
210            EXAMPLE7BOTL-C
42             EXAMPLE4BOTL
30             EXAMPLE1BOTL
28             EXAMPLE12BOTL
100            EXAMPLE7BOTL
97             EXAMPLE4BOTL
29             EXAMPLE7BOTL-C
```

What I want it to be

```
Quantity        SKU
536             _Example
```

I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.  A SQL Fiddle can also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Given your data, just use `case`:

```
select (case when left(sku, 1) = '_' then '_Example' else sku end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't change data just to do a sum(). I would go with:

```
SELELCT   
CASE WHEN SKU LIKE '%EXAMP%' THEN '_Example' ELSE SKU END AS SKU,
SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM test.dbo.tblSFCOrderTxn
GROUP BY CASE WHEN SKU LIKE '%EXAMP%' THEN '_Example' ELSE SKU END
ORDER BY 1
```

If you really do want to change the data, it would be:

```
UPDATE test.dbo.tblSFCOrderTxn
SET SKU = '_Example'
WHERE SKU LIKE '%EXAMP%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity),'_Example' AS SKU FROM test.dbo.tblSFCOrderTxn GROUP BY CASE SKU WHEN '1' THEN '1' ELSE '2' END
```